# SQL Server: Ways to impose Uniqueness on columns from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design, unique-constraint

Sample tables:

> - dbo.TransactionHeader (HeaderID, BillID, FileID) -- HeaderID is the PK here
> - dbo.TransactionGroup (FileID, SurityID) -- All these make a composite PK

I want to impose uniqueness on `BillID` from table `dbo.TransactionHeader` and another column (`SurityID`) from another table `dbo.TransactionGroup`. `SurityID` is not available in the `dbo.TransactionHeader` table.

I want to add uniqueness on `dbo.TransactionHeader` table, to not insert any duplicates with (`BillID, SurityID`) combination.

I cannot add a new physical column(say `SurityID`) in `dbo.TransactionHeader` as its a legacy database with lots of data and it will be a big change.

`Options tried:`
Tried to create computed column and tried using a function to get the `SurityID` based on `FileID`. But cannot create unique constraint on computed column as the function returns a non-deterministic value

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your query you wrote so we can get a better idea of the result set you're looking for? If you claim you can't add a new column does that mean you are you looking for help on a JOIN query or something else?

Comment: You cannot do this with a declarative constraint - those cannot span tables. All you could potentially do is write an `INSERT` trigger on `dbo.TransactionHeader` to check if such a problematic combination already exists - and if so, reject the insert operatoin

Comment: @PausePause: This is not about data retrieval. I am trying to impose uniqueness on the existing system, while inserting the data to table dbo.TransactionHeader which has some design considerations, so that it will not impact/eliminate the need to change other processes which are inserting data to this table.

Comment: @marc_s: The trigger worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, found that we can also use `CHECK` constraint to achieve this.

Steps:

Create a `user defined function`, which will return `0` or `1`, after checking the the existence of duplicates like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TransactionHeader_Bill_ID_Surity_ID](@File_ID INT,@Bill_ID VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[TransactionHeader] AS th
            WHERE th.Bill_ID = @Bill_ID) > 0
            BEGIN            
            DECLARE @Surity_ID SMALLINT = (SELECT Surity_ID FROM [dbo].[TransactionGroup] WHERE File_ID = @File_ID)

            IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [dbo].[TransactionHeader] AS th 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[TransactionGroup] AS tg ON tg.File_ID = th.File_ID 
                WHERE th.Bill_ID = @Bill_ID
                AND  tg.Surity_ID = @Surity_ID) > 1
                BEGIN
                    RETURN 1
                END
          END
RETURN 0
END
GO
```

Now add a `CHECK` constraint on `dbo.TransactionHeader`(`Bill_ID`)

column and embed the above function in `CHECK` constraint expression like below:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TransactionHeader]  WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TransactionHeader_Bill_ID 
CHECK (dbo.udf_TransactionHeader_Bill_ID_Surity_ID(SurityID,Bill_ID) = 0);
```

This should achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an indexed view. Example:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v1 WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT H.HeaderID, H.BillID, H.FileId, G.SurityID
FROM dbo.TransactionHeader H
JOIN dbo.TransactionGroup G
ON H.FileID = G.FileID;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v1idx ON dbo.v1 (BillID, SurityID) ;
```